# GraphQL Prisma database that allows two tables to have relations to one table

Tags: database, postgresql, orm, graphql, prisma

I'm looking to have relational tables that connects two different tables to the one table.

```
type User {
  booking: [Booking!]! @relation(name: "UserToBooking" onDelete: SET_NULL)
}

type Booking {
  owner: User! @relation(name: "UserToBooking", onDelete: SET_NULL)
  renter: [User!]! @relation(name: "UserToBooking", onDelete: SET_NULL)
}
```

Prisma only allows one of the same relation so having two "UserToBooking" is not possible.  What's the best way to create a relation that allows to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to have two different booking types. I'm guessing this is something like an AirBnB arrangement where a user can own a property that is rented out and/or also rent properties from others. I think you should specify two different items in your User type to distinguish these, and then have a relationship for these. Something like this:

```
type User {
  booking: [Booking!]! @relation(name: "UserToBooking" onDelete: CASCADE)
  let: [Booking!]! @relation(name: "UserToLetBooking" onDelete: CASCADE)
}

type Booking {
  owner: User! @relation(name: "UserToLetBooking", onDelete: SET_NULL)
  renter: User! @relation(name: "UserToBooking", onDelete: SET_NULL)
}
```

This way the booking shows a user who is the letting owner and a user who is the renter. I have also changed the renter in booking to a single user because I figure each booking has 1 letting owner and 1 renter. I also changed the onDelete setting for the user type so that if a user is deleted any of his bookings or lets are also deleted. This would be a typical pattern but is up to you.

Comment: you provide a valid solution. I'll try implementing this.  Renter is an array because there will be multiple people renting the same property over time.